# Strange Google Search results for Salesforce topics

Tags: discussion

I've been Googling for Salesforce info and I've seen a few results where the result was not on the site "salesforce.stackexchange.com", but I ended up on  a page that started with

salesforce.stackexchang.net

What's going on with that?  Is someone trying to hijack stackexchange traffic?

Comment: Do you have any proofs like screenshots or something else? It would be interesting to take a look. I`ve just tried to search for some SFDC infos and could find only reasonable results...

Comment: the domain is being hosted ( http://salesforce.stackexchang.net/ ), i'm interested in actual pages too. Let's hope it's not a phishing attempt.

Comment: Sorry, didn't save any screen shots.  I'll see if I can replicate the search I did yesterday.  Might not have a chance til late this afternoon.

Comment: Can't reproduce yesterday's results.  I'm sure I was seeing search results that in no way resembled salesforce.stackexchange.com that then redirected me to broken salesforce.stackexchang.net pages.

Comment: I've seen it too. It seems to replicate answers from SFSE and mimic the results on it's own ad-laden website.

Comment: anything u can recover from ur browser history ?

Answer (score 1):

All I could find out are the following results that has topics replicated from **salesforce.stackexchang.net**.

[image: result from a different site]

The results are not cached, which means it can't be accessed any more.

Similar title, summary and description in the results. Hats off copycat!